# using php mysql to insert into two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im trying to insert data into two tables, i need to have an auto-increment in both tables one is book_id which is in the books table, and the other is auth_id in the authors table.

i need the author to be traced to a book.

here is my html code and php code that i am using.

any help would be much appreciated.

the HTML code is:-

```
 <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="database3.php" >
      <label for="fname">First Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" placeholder="John" required="required" />
      <label for="auth-name">Second Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
      <input type="text" id="sname" name="sname" value="" placeholder="Doe" required="required" /><br />
      <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required="required" />  
      <label for="telephone">Telephone: <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="" placeholder="" required="required" /><br />

      <label for="genre">Genre:  <span class="required">*</span></label>  
      <select id="genre" name="genre" placeholder="please select one..." required="required">
        <option value="please-select">Please select one..</option>
        <option text="murder_mystery" value="1">Murder Mystery</option>  
        <option text="romance" value="2">Romance</option>  
        <option text="sci_fi" value="3">Sci-Fi</option>  
        <option text="horror" value="4">Horror</option>  
        <option text="thriller" value="5">Thriller</option>  
        <option text="screen_plays" value="6">Screen Play's</option>  
        <option text="poetry" value="7">Poetry</option>  
        <option text="childrens" value="8">Children's</option>  
        <option text="non_fiction" value="9">Non-Fiction</option>  
        <option text="comedy" value="11">Comedy</option>  
        <option text="other" value="10">Other</option>
      </select>
      <label for="numpages">Number of Pages: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
      <select id="numpages" name="numpages">  
        <option value="num-page">Please Select one..</option>  
        <option value="0-100">0-100</option>  
        <option value="100-300">100-300</option>  
        <option value="300-500">300-500</option>
        <option value="500">500+</option>
      </select><br />
      <label for="booktitle">Book Title: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
      <input type="text" id="booktitle" name="booktitle" value="" placeholder="John Doe" required="required" />
      <br />
      <label for="description">Book Description: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
      <textarea id="bookdescription" name="description" placeholder="max 40 words describing your work, this will effectively be how you sell your bookto the reader" required="required" data-minlength="20"></textarea>
      <br />
      <label for="synopsis">Book Synopsis: <span class="required">*</span></label>  
      <textarea id="synopsis" name="synopsis" placeholder="max 100 words of the synopsis of your book,to the reader"
       required="required" data-minlength="20"></textarea>
      <br />
      <label for="file">Filename:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
      <br />
      <label for="check_tc">Do you agree to the T&C<span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check_tc" name="check_tc" required="required" />
      <br />

      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit-button" />  
</form>
```

the php code is:-

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if(!$connection)
{
 die("database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db("good-read", $connection);
if(!$db_select)
{
die("database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO author (auth_first, auth_second, auth_email, auth_telephone)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[sname]','$_POST[email]', '$_POST[telephone]')";

mysql_query($sql, $connection);

echo "1 record added";

$sql_book = "INSERT INTO book (book_title, book_num_pages, book_genre_id, book_description, book_synopsis)
VALUES
('$_POST[booktitle]', '$_POST[numpages]', '$_POST[genre]','$_POST[description]', '$_POST[synopsis]')";


mysql_query($sql_book, $connection);

echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking how to fill in `auth_id` when inserting the book?

Comment: Two things:

1.)  You should **seriously** consider switching to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

2.)  To answer, what I think is your question, if you want to relate the author to books, you should use some sort of ID.  Depending on how complex your database structure is you might want to use a foreign-key set up.  So, for instance, you'd have an Author with an ID of 1, and every book hes written will have a property of "author_id".

Comment: Obligatory notice: `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. Your code is susceptible to SQL injection attacks. Make sure you use 'real_escape_string()` on all your `$_POST` variables, or usde prepared statements.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Answer (score -3):

`mysql_insert_id()` returns the auto-increment ID assigned in the last `INSERT`. Use that to fill in the `auth_id` column in the `book` row.  Also, note carefully that I have refactored your code to use `mysqli` prepared statements.  This will help to avoid things like injection attacks.

```
$auth_id = mysql_insert_id($connection);
$sql_book = "INSERT INTO book (auth_id, book_title, book_num_pages, book_genre_id, book_description, book_synopsis)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_book);
$stmt->bind_param("ississ", $auth_id, $_POST[booktitle], $_POST[numpages], $_POST[genre], $_POST[description], $_POST[synopsis]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: This, like the original, is completely reckless due to a complete lack of escaping.

Comment: Why the downvote? Because I didn't fix all the SQL injection problems? I'm just answering the question, I'm not teaching him how to rewrite his code to solve all the other problems. The comments above address that adequately.

Comment: You can omit the query. Your one line about using `mysql_insert_id` is sufficient. Quoting that code is akin to endorsing it, saying, in effect, "This is how I would do it."

Comment: Putting `$_POST` variables in queries is a habit that needs to be stomped out completely. I'm sorry about being such a curmudgeon, but unless people like you that know better take the small amount of time to demonstrate the correct way of doing it, people won't break their old habits.

Comment: Why don't YOU post a better answer, instead of complaining about mine?

Comment: I'm not complaining, I'm explaining my protest vote. Would adding `mysql_real_escape_string` to illustrate how to fix the escaping problem be too much to ask?

Comment: it's just a lot of typing that I don't feel like doing, since it's unrelated to the question.

Comment: I can only suppose "It's just a lot of typing" explains why most PHP apps are riddled with SQL injection bugs.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I'm in a totally different mode when I'm programming for real and just answering SO questions. I'm not going to spend 15 minutes writing a totally polished answer.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161760/php-echo-results-where-input-like-get/19161809#19161809) where the person answering the question took a few extra seconds to fix the problem and explain why. Demonstrating is the best way to teach. It never ceases to amaze me that people will spend half an hour arguing why they don't need to spend that short amount of time.

Comment: Will you please get off my case. Instead of bitching at me, post a better answer. I'll even upvote you.

Comment: `get off my case` ... while Barman's original answer did have a SQL injection problem, it did, in fact, answer the OP and was not any _worse_.