# PHP Echo results where input LIKE $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement a hashtag system into my website. I have it set so user input that has a hashtag gets converted into a link to hashtag.php?q=%23$1 that echo's "Results for '.$_GET["q"].':"; which works fine, but it doesn't actually display any posts.
For example, I have a post saying "This #website sucks" which is echoed out as

```
This <a href="hashtag.php?q=%23website">#website</a> sucks
```

But the following page only displays

```
Results for #website:
```

and the rest is blank. Here's my code for hashtag.php:

```
echo 'Results for '.$_GET["q"].':';

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database",$connect);
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE input LIKE '".$_GET['q']."' ";
$myData = mysql_query($mysql, $connect);
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo $record['input'];
}
```

I'm working on using mysqli before I make the site public by the way.

Comment: I recommend to **immediately** stop using your code. It is completely open to SQL injection. What if I pass `'; DROP TABLE table'` for `$_GET[q]` ?

Comment: Are you sure that your query is returning results?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO : +1 for effort, but your code will not do anything, as you can't run multiple commands :P

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO it wouldn't work because `ext/mysql` does not allow multiple queries to be executed with one function simultaneously.  *However*, he should use properly parameterized queries to prevent injection.

Comment: You probably need to add wildcards (`%`) to your `LIKE` like `LIKE '%".$_GET['q']."%'`

Comment: @ExplosionPills It is for dramatic effect. :)

Comment: Adding the % works, as stated by Jonathon and FDL. Thanks for the advice. You guys know how to quickly fix this?
"mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given"
where "mysqli_select_db('database', $connect);" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting % percentage signs on either side of the `$_GET["p"]` in your query. Don't forget to escape the `$_GET["q"]` as well. That'd be more important than using mysqli ;)

```
$mysql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE input LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q'])."%' ";
```